# Root Level of Treeview in Silverlight Missing "Triangle" Icon

Tags: silverlight, xaml, treeview

For some reason, a treeview I'm buildling in Silverlight has decided it no longer wants to display the triangle associated with the root level. It still functions correctly though. Pictures below:

[image: tree1] 
 
[image: tree2]

As you can see, it is just the root level that is exhibiting this behavior. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Please include the relevant Xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head into a wall for awhile about this one. I got it, here's the source:

```
    public void HandleGroupData(ObservableCollection<Group> groupTree)
    {
        foreach (var group in groupTree)
        {
            var groupNode = new TreeNode(group.DisplayText, ENodeType.Group, group.Id);
            GetSubitemsOfGroup(group, groupNode);
            RootLevel.Add(groupNode);
        }
    }
```

We build the TreeView from the database. Originally the RootLevel.Add and GetSubitems calls were in reverse order. GetSubitems is a routine that recursively is called building the tree in a DFS. What I believe was happening was that we were adding a node to the tree that had no children, so initially the Silverlight GUI builder thought that they had no child nodes so didn't give them little triangles.

Moral of the story: Watch the ordering of tree view creation!